# Apache Flink: Using filter() or split() to split a stream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a DataStream from Kafka which has 2 possible value for a field in MyModel. MyModel is a pojo with domain-specific fields parsed from a message from Kafka.

```
DataStream<MyModel> stream = env.addSource(myKafkaConsumer);
```

I want to apply window and operators on each key a1, a2 separately. What is a good way to separate them? I have 2 options filter and select in mind but don't know which one is faster.

**Filter approach**

```
stream
        .filter(<MyModel.a == a1>)
        .keyBy()
        .window()
        .apply()
        .addSink()

stream
        .filter(<MyModel.a == a2>)
        .keyBy()
        .window()
        .apply()
        .addSink()
```

**Split and select approach**

```
SplitStream<MyModel> split = stream.split(…)
    split
        .select(<MyModel.a == a1>)
        …
        .addSink()

    split
        .select<MyModel.a == a2>()
        …
        .addSink()
```

If split and select are better, how to implement them if I want to split based on the value of a field in MyModel?

Comment: I'd recommend NOT use `split`.

Maybe I did something wrong but in my current project `env.execute()` throws weird exception when using split. Then I replaced `split` with `filter` and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both methods behave pretty much the same. Internally, the `split()` operator forks the stream and applies filters as well.

There is a third option, [Side Outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html) . Side outputs might have some benefits, such as different output data types. Moreover, the filter condition is just evaluated once for side outputs.

Answer (score 5):

[SplitStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/SplitStream.html)s and [split](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#split-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.collector.selector.OutputSelector-) method in [DataStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html) are deprecated since [Flink Deprecated List 1.6](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/deprecated-list.html). It is no longer recommended to be used.

Comment: So what should be use instead? 
I want to "split" my stream based on field value that will result with me having two different streams that I can later process in a different way.

Comment: @Kristoff You can use the `filter` transformation as demonstrated above. You call it twice on your "input" stream with different conditions (e.g. >0, <=0) and effectively split the dataflow.

This works for [`DataSet`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/api/java/DataSet.html) as well.